# Trouble instantiating a JavaKeyStore from file

Tags: java, security, cryptography, keystore, jks

I'm trying to get an instance of `org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin` using `org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory` specifically the `CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties)` method.

This will consistantly throw

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin cannot create instance`

which evantually is caused by

`java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed`

The password on the keystore file has been checked with the keytool on the command line and is correct.

the keystore is generated via the following process:

[image: CMD Window detailing keytool -genkey -keystore testkeystore.jks]

Which is in the root directory of the eclipse porject.

The test applciation is as follows:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CredentialException,
            IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password",
                "password");
        p.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider",
                "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
        p.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type",
                "jks");
        p.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", "./testkeystore.jks");

        Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance(p);
        System.out.println(" Complete ");

    }
}
```

and the following exception is generated:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin cannot create instance
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.loadClass(CryptoFactory.java:225)
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.loadClass(CryptoFactory.java:180)
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:73)
    at com.restart.test.cryptotest2.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.loadClass(CryptoFactory.java:211)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CredentialException: Failed to load credentials.
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.AbstractCrypto.load(AbstractCrypto.java:174)
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.AbstractCrypto.<init>(AbstractCrypto.java:135)
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.<init>(Merlin.java:71)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.AbstractCrypto.load(AbstractCrypto.java:168)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770)
    ... 13 more
```

The password as indicated in the cmd window is set to "password" , but by all accounts the application is rejecting it, I can change the password using `keytool -storepasswd` with no issues, So i know the the password I am providing is correct; can anyone suggest what may be going wrong here? I've been trying to debug this unsuccessfully for full a day now.

If there is any additional information I can provide please let me know.

edit --

the folloing maven dependency is required to build this test:

```
   <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId> 
      <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId> 
      <version>1.5.8</version> 
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Just repeat your steps with Oracle JDK 1.6 and it work without any error. Maybe your password is incorrect or you trying to open different keystore? Try to re-create it and set absolute path to keystore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the comments from User I built it against a different version of the JDK/JRE and it worked, after downloading the sources for rt.java and stepping through I found that the CryptoBase class was instantiating two JavaKeyStores, the first (being my .jks file) which instantiated fine, but the second was the `cacerts` keystore in `jre\lib\security>` which did not have the default password of `changeit` which was causing the failure;

I have now changed the password on the jre keystore and I'm working fine in my original jre/jdk.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is related with libraries because stacktrace says

'org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin cannot create instance'

it means you don't have (o have an incorrect version) of WSS4J library.